# Normal CSS with CSS Modules

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I was previously using bootstrap css import fine previously.

However I'm trying to use CSS module so I added a few lines.

```
  {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use:  [
          'style-loader',
          { 
            loader: 'css-loader', 
            options: { 
              importLoaders: 1, 
              modules: true, //<- Added to enable css module
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' //<-Added to enable css module
            }
          },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
```

Now I'm able to use the following sample codes

```
  import styles from 'styles.css'
```

and use it in the code like this

```
  <div className={styles.container}></div>
```

and it becomes like this in browser

```
  <div class="styles__container___3dfEE"></div>
```

**I have the following in my index.js**

```
  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

**Now, all my classes from bootstrap.min.css are no longer working.**

**How can i enable both css modules as well as continue to use bootstrap css normally?**

I'm currently using a "dirty" way to do it, by saving my custom styles as styles.sss instead and added the following codes in webpack config. Not sure whether it will have any issues.

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use:  [
      'style-loader',
      { 
        loader: 'css-loader', 
        options: { 
          importLoaders: 1
        }
      },
      'postcss-loader'
    ]
  },
    {
    test: /\.sss$/,
    use:  [
      'style-loader',
      { 
        loader: 'css-loader', 
        options: { 
          importLoaders: 1, 
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        }
      },
      'postcss-loader'
    ]
  }
```

Comment: What version of the css-loader, style-loader and postcss-loader do you use?

Comment: "style-loader": "^0.18.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.5", I'm using a boilerplate so I may not be able to update them to latest version for all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to import bootstrap's css without going through your original webpack config:

```
import "!style-loader!css-loader!bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

this will activate the style-loader and css loader but without the `modules: true` option

Comment: simple and easy, thanks for the solution without changing all my webpack prod/dev/ssr files.

Answer (score 0):

I have learnt few methods before for this [Github pull-request issue](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/pull/65).

---

First, change the file name. Easiest way but ugly.

Change your `styles.css` to `styles.m.css` and separate module and plain css like

```
//Module
test: /\.m.css$/
//Plain
test: /\^((?!\.m).)*css$/
```

---

Second, separate the folders for module and plain css, while exclude each other.

```
//Module
exclude: /css/plain/
//Plain
exclude: /css/module/
```

---

Third, use `resourceQuery`

```
test: /\.css$/,
oneOf: [{
    resourceQuery: /^\?raw$/,
    use: [...]
}
```

And import as

```
import './bootstrap.min.css?raw'
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the loaders into different rules. Like this:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use:  [
    'style-loader',
  ]
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use:  [
    { 
      loader: 'css-loader', 
      options: { 
        importLoaders: 1, 
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      }
    },
    'postcss-loader'
  ]
}
```

Comment: this didn't help.. but the accepted answer is sufficient. Thank u!